# CSS Angular Tag <

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is the use of using angular tag in css

ie,

```
.class << span
```

but Normally we are using these types of tag

```
body
{
    background-color:#d0e4fe;
}
h1
{
    color:orange;
    text-align:center;
}
p
{
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `<<` in css.

Comment: Where did you see the use of `<<`? What does the second block of code have to do with your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not valid CSS. `>` is the child combinator but `<` and `<<` are meaningless in selector syntax.

Answer (score 1):

One of the uses of angular brackets in CSS is the `>` as the child selector. (search ["css child selectors"](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=child%20selector%20css&qscrl=1) for more)