# Whats the meaning of "<" or ">" on css?

Tags: css

I see code css below:

`#nav .hover > a`

Whats the meaning of ">" or "<" on code above ? Anyone can explain to me?
Thank you.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Where did you see `<`? This is eerily similar to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649244/css-angular-tag) where the questioner claims to have seen `<<` in CSS.

Comment: this post will help you understand what it means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ">" mean in CSS rules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>` is called the **[child selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html)**.
You take all `a`'s that are **direct children** of `#nav .hover`.

The symbol `<` is not allowed, as it's not to be understood as "less than" or "larger than".

Comment: Or just the child selector, because that's what the word child means.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `<` in CSS. Where as, the `>` is used for direct child selector.

Say, there are many elements in `#nav .hover`. Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
  <div class="hover">
    <a href="#">Direct Link</a>
    <p><a href="#">Indirect Link</a> is this.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code `#nav .hover > a` will select only the Direct Link.

Where as, if you put something like `#nav .hover a`, it will select all the links under `#nav .hover`. i.e., it will select both Direct as well as Indirect Link.

Answer (score 0):

It selects only children of that element. In other word:

```
#menu li:hover > ul { display:block; }
```

would make the style for any `<ul>`s inside of that `<li>` (such with dropdown menus) `display:block`

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?